# Storing a JSON of class with a reference to an object of the same class

Tags: java, json, design-patterns

I have something similar to this:

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public List<Person> family;
}
List<Person> people;
```

And I want to store **people** as a JSON string on disk. And I want to follow a good design pattern. Like *doing it the right way*.

I don't want to end up with

```
[{"name":"John Doe", "family": [{"name": "Mary", "family": [{"name": "Mary's mother", "family": [{.........
```

Also one could end up with Mary having John Doe as family too, making a endless recursion.

What I would like to end up is with something like this:

```
[{"name":"John Doe", "family": [(reference to Mary)]}, {"name": "Mary", "family": [(reference to Mary's Mother), (reference to John Doe)]}, ...]
```

I don't want to assume the *name* is unique.

Is adding an "ID" to Person a good implementation/pattern? Because in my class a Person with an ID doesn't make sense (they don't have/need one)

The idea I have in mind (which I think would be a good design pattern) is to have another "private" class

```
private class PersonWithId extends Person {
    private int id;
}
```

and store that PersonWithId in the JSON so when storing the family List, i can store the ID as the reference so there is no recursion.

What options do I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Using a unique identifier to identify a person is a good idea.   You could use a UUID - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Depending on the volume of data (people) you want to store, it may make more sense to use (something like) Redis to store the JSon for each Person -> Family (using a UUID as your key).

Comment: Should I put the UUID inside People? or make another class?

Comment: You can start off with your PersonWithId (which) extends Person.

Answer (score 2):

I am limiting the scope of my answer to the direct question of adding unique identifier to serialized instances and avoiding circular references.

[Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) has support for circular references.  You can manage the generation of unique identifier and tell jackson to refer to it, or let Jackson generate unique identifier in the json.  The library will be able to load such json back into memory:

```
// annotation that tells jackson to generate sequantial int unique id
// and add it as "@id" property
// this will also be used in de-serialization
@JsonIdentityInfo(
    generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class,
    property="@id")
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public List<Person> family = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person john = new Person();
    john.name = "John Doe";
    Person mary = new Person();
    mary.name = "Mary";
    john.family.add(mary);
    mary.family.add(john);
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    people.add(john);
    people.add(mary);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        // serialize the list into json
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(people);
        System.out.println(json);

        // de-serialize the json into list of persons
        people = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Person>>(){});
        people.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.name));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
[{"@id":1,"name":"John Doe","family":[{"@id":2,"name":"Mary","family":[1]}]},2]
John Doe
Mary
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this.

```
public class Person {

private static Map<UUID, Person> persons = new HashMap<>();

//some dummy data
static {
    final UUID uuidMax = UUID.randomUUID();
    persons.put(uuidMax, new Person("Max", null));
    persons.put(UUID.randomUUID(), new Person("John", Arrays.asList(uuidMax)));
}

public static String saveAsJSON() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(persons); 
    //or write right away gson.toJson(obj, new FileWriter("D:\\file.json"));
}

public static void addFromJSON(String json) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    persons = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class); 
    //plug in JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename)) to read directly from file
}

private String name;
private List<UUID> family;

public Person(String name, List<UUID> family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

//returns family member if it exists
public Person getFamilyMember(UUID id) {
    if(persons.containsKey(id))
        return persons.get(id);
    return null;
}

//returns the entire family
public List<Person> getFamilyMembers() {
    List<Person> family = new LinkedList<>();
    if(this.family != null) {
        for (var cur : this.family) {
            var person = getFamilyMember(cur);
            if(person != null)
                family.add(person);
            else
                this.family.remove(cur); //person no longer exists

        }
    }
    return family;
}
```

}

Used the GSON Library for that

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

UUID is great because you don´t need to worry about generating unique IDs as they are generally unique, that´s the point. In theory you could get duplicates, but it is very extremely unlikely.

The String it spits out, looks like this then

```
{"bced5dcf-102c-4d18-9f92-bb10d7a5b212":{"name":"Max"},"e40710b4-55b5-4e97-a280-6d07ae160e3b":{"name":"John","family":["bced5dcf-102c-4d18-9f92-bb10d7a5b212"]}}
```

You probably wanna put the Save/Read stuff into another class, but I just put it all in there as an example.

Comment: there is no explanation how the solution is built. the purpose of this site is not to provide code, it is to provide *solutions*. and there is way way too much unrelated code that obscures the solution (with all the getters and setters)

Comment: and what is "region generated-stuff"

Comment: Just a note that those things i didnt write. I let Intellij make them. Regions im used to using in C#, not sure if its actually technically a real comment construct in Java, but intellij sure works with it and lets you fold away everything in it and that makes it kinda handy to sort things in classes as you can fold away stuff thats not important for what youre implementing at that point. Just a note that should tell you that that part is not really very interesting. Sure, I could have just not used properties. Im just used to doing it anyways, since its 1 click away to have them.

Comment: well, I also use Intellij. ("The Java IDE") and I use it to actually develop Java applications and I have never seen "region generated-stuff" in Java code. and if its not interesting, then make the small effort to remove it. so that us, human readers, who are not IDE, will e able to focus on what's important

Comment: In my opinion, it is too much code for what I was looking for. But I could take from this the idea of having family members as another thing internally (something that would not make the recursion) but externally have the List<Person> getFamily()